# Halting looping till the service result is obtained in wp7

Tags: web-services, for-loop, windows-phone

I am new to Windows Phone Development.

I am using a for loop to call webservice for each element in the list. I want to go to the next loop only after the result from service is obtained. My loop is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            selectedInfo = lstReorderItems[i];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedInfo.ItemCostVariantValueIDs))
            {
                client.AddItemstoCartCompleted += client_AddItemstoCartCompleted;
                client.AddItemstoCartAsync(//params);
            }
            else
            {
                client.CheckItemQuantityInCartCompleted += client_CheckItemQuantityInCartCompleted;
                client.CheckItemQuantityInCartAsync(//params);
            }
        }
```

But the loop continues without waiting the result to come. So can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

After going through the question, what i understood is, you are making **series web service call**. Which in my opinion is **not good**, because to get final result user have to wait, until all the service call gets finished and there is **chance to get failure response in mid way**, which will also block final result. So go for parallel calls, to support that WebClient is designed with background options.

If it is completely necessary, then declare the looping variable as class member

```
Public class xxxxxx
{
  int i = (startCount ) 0;
```

Then start the service as usual,

```
 selectedInfo = lstReorderItems[i];
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedInfo.ItemCostVariantValueIDs))
  {
        client.AddItemstoCartCompleted += client_AddItemstoCartCompleted;
        client.AddItemstoCartAsync(//params);
  }
```

at the service response completed event, in your case client_AddItemstoCartCompleted call the same service after incrementing looping variable, before that you have to compare looping variable with count
as

```
if(i< count)
{
 i++;
 selectedInfo = lstReorderItems[i];
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedInfo.ItemCostVariantValueIDs))
   {
      client.AddItemstoCartAsync(//params);
   }
}
```